# Windows Phone, pick file using PickSingleFileAndContinue or PickMultipleFilesAndContinue

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I got stuck trying to implementing file picker for windows phone app. I need to choose files from gallery using `FileOpenPicker`. I didn't get how it works. Here is my code:

```
private readonly FileOpenPicker photoPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

// This is a constructor
public MainPage()
{
    // < ... >

    photoPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    photoPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
}

// I have button on the UI. On click, app shows picker where I can choose a file
private void bChoosePhoto_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    photoPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue();
}
```

So, what to do next? I guess I need to get a file object or something.

I found [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631755.aspx). It is msdn explanation where custom class `ContinuationManager` is implemented. This solution looks weird and ugly. I am not sure if it is the best one. Please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

PickAndContinue is the [only method that would work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx) on Windows Phone 8.1. It's not so weird and ugly, here goes a simple example without *ContinuationManager*:

Let's assume that you want to pick a *.jpg* file, you use FileOpenPicker:

```
FileOpenPicker picker = new FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.ContinuationData.Add("keyParameter", "Parameter"); // some data which you can pass 
picker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

Once you run `PickSingleFileAndContinue();`, your app is deactivated. When you finish picking a file, then `OnActivated` event is fired, where you can read the file(s) you have picked:

```
protected async override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var continuationEventArgs = args as IContinuationActivatedEventArgs;
    if (continuationEventArgs != null)
    {
        switch (continuationEventArgs.Kind)
        {
            case ActivationKind.PickFileContinuation:
                FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs arguments = continuationEventArgs as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;
                string passedData = (string)arguments.ContinuationData["keyParameter"];
                StorageFile file = arguments.Files.FirstOrDefault(); // your picked file
                // do what you want
                break;
        // rest of the code - other continuation, window activation etc.
```

Note that when you run file picker, your app is deactivated and in some rare situations it can be terminated by OS (little resources for example).

The *ContinuationManager* is only a *helper* that should help to make some things easier. Of course, you can implement your own behaviour for simpler cases.

Comment: I am not able to get OnActivated method. This method not found to override.

Comment: OnActivated method is found in Application class of Windows.UI.Xaml namespace and  Windows.UI.Xaml is not available for windows phone. Any idea for this fix ?