# Sharing A File On Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, app.xaml

May someone help im coding my own universal windows store app i want my xaml page to select a file then share it using the share contract on windows phone 8.1 . The problem is my windows phone 8.1 app when i select a file it hits a break point and does no recognize this line of code  IReadOnlyList pickedFiles = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync(). This works on the Windows 8.1 version not the Windows Phone 8.1 version.

```
private async void SelectFilesButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker filePicker = new FileOpenPicker
        {
            ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List,
            SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary,
            FileTypeFilter = { "*" }
        };

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> pickedFiles = await filePicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

        if (pickedFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            this.storageItems = pickedFiles;

            // Display the file names in the UI.
            string selectedFiles = String.Empty;
            for (int index = 0; index < pickedFiles.Count; index++)
            {
                selectedFiles += pickedFiles[index].Name;

                if (index != (pickedFiles.Count - 1))
                {
                    selectedFiles += ", ";
                }
            }

            NotifyUser(String.Format("Picked files: ") + selectedFiles + ".", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            ShareStep.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        DataTransferManager dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
        dataTransferManager.DataRequested += new TypedEventHandler<DataTransferManager,
            DataRequestedEventArgs>(this.ShareStorageItemsHandler);
        // If the user clicks the share button, invoke the share flow programatically.
        DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();


    }

    private async void ShareStorageItemsHandler(DataTransferManager sender,DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRequest request = e.Request;
        request.Data.Properties.Title = TitleInputBox.Text;
        request.Data.Properties.Description = DescriptionInputBox.Text;

        // Because we are making async calls in the DataRequested event handler,
        // we need to get the deferral first.
        DataRequestDeferral deferral = request.GetDeferral();

        // Make sure we always call Complete on the deferral.
        try
        {


            request.Data.SetStorageItems(this.storageItems);
        }
        finally
        {
            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The file picker API on Windows Phone 8.1 works slightly differently. Instead of FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync you need to call FileOpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAndContinue. This article provides much more context: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn631755.aspx. This is also covered in my Build talk here: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-520.

Finally, the answer to this: [Windows Phone, pick file using PickSingleFileAndContinue or PickMultipleFilesAndContinue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011016/windows-phone-pick-file-using-picksinglefileandcontinue-or-pickmultiplefilesand) StackOverflow question also has a sample.

Answer (score 0):

In the preview of the Win10 SDK this works the same as on WinRT, so both Phone & anything else will just use PickMultipleFilesAsync