# How to relate between open file picker and storage file?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, storagefile

**look for this error and tell me your opinion to solve this problem** 
I was making window phone Application :
**its can't save my picked file in a storage file to trim it as media**
or I can not relate between open file picker and storage file if anyone have any ideas how to relate between them or have any demos please tell me

Comment: Code or it didn't happen

Comment: Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = openpicker.PickSingleFileAndContinue(); @Anton

Comment: @AlpirGeorge this line of code will only open the File Picker, and you have to handle the OnActivated() event when the user finish select the file.  A useful code snippet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011016/windows-phone-pick-file-using-picksinglefileandcontinue-or-pickmultiplefilesand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem. Here is my code for picking a file and write into it in WinRT/Win10 store app.

```
private async void SaveFileExecute()
{
    var fileNameTab = FileName.Split('.');
    var extension = fileNameTab[1];
    var fileName = fileNameTab[0];
    var savePicker = new FileSavePicker
    {
        SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary,
        SuggestedFileName = fileName
    };

    savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(extension, new List<string> { "." + extension });

    var saveFile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    if (saveFile != null)
    {
        using (var fileStream = await saveFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (var outputStream = fileStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0))
            {
                using (var dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream))
                {
                    dataWriter.WriteBytes(SelectedFile.Data);
                    await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                    dataWriter.DetachStream();
                }

                await outputStream.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```